# WiFi signal strength in a script

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w, php

I have a need to obtain WiFi signal strength on a Pi0W.

I have a PHP script and all works via terminal: `php /var/www/html/blah.php` (I use `exec("iwconfig wlan0", $output_lines);`)

The script runs as a cron job.

Basically, cron launches `curl` every 5 minutes to send a ping to another server (this part works). I `POST` some `JSON` data which gets processed on the server. This used to be a static .json file. Now I generate my `JSON` data on the fly and want/need to include some additional data with it.

The command launched by cron:

```
curl -d "`php /var/www/html/generate_json.php`" -X POST https://myserver/json_logger.php
```

The `JSON` data generates fine, but I am having trouble retrieving the result of `iwconfig`

The funny thing is when I run the `php` part in a terminal, it gets the data fine (kind of expected). I also checked `whoami` and I am "pi" (as expected).

When the command is launched by cron, it is also launched by "pi" user; however, as I stated above, the result of `iwconfig` is blank.

As I understand, this is most likely a permissions issue, but I am not sure exactly what/where to change.

If there is another way to obtain WiFi information, I am open to options.

Comment: Have you added the www-data user to the groups to allow it to control the WiFi interface? `sudo usermod -a -G netdev www-data`

Comment: No, I haven't, but the funny thing is, this morning I found it to be working. No changes since last night when I made a post and it just refused to work (the output array was blank), but this morning it seems fine. Just now I added `cat /proc/net/wireless` to the script and they both grab the data just fine. Thanks for the comment, I will keep it in mind if I have a similar issue.

Comment: This week I finally had the time to get back to this project. Turns out, I was wrong. The successful pings that I saw were from when I manually launched the script a few-times in a row, then unplugged the Pi, and some time later looked at the server. @Dougie, as per your device, I've added `www-data` to the `netdev` group, but it doesn't seem to change the behaviour. When I run the script it works, when `curl` does it, I get no output from `iwconfig`. While it would be a good experience to get this working, all I really need is a WiFi connection info (network SSID, signal strength, etc.).